# Is there anything special about renderer.js in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I understand the difference between `renderer.js` and `main.js` in Electron, but what I don't understand is why Electron suggests the existence of a `renderer.js` file in the first place. In truth, `renderer.js` is just a JS file being included in the app's `index.html`....it would be no different if you called it `index.js`. It even says in their examples "include as many other scripts here as you wish." So it's actually just the same as a normal web page....you just include JS, and the file called `renderer.js` isn't strictly necessary nor any different from any other included JS.

Do I have this right?

Comment: I believe according to the documentation, I believe you are correct.    But where is it that you are getting  that "Electron suggests the existence of a renderer.js" from?

Comment: The only place in the repo where I could even find that term was here https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/lib/sandboxed_renderer/init.js#L155

Comment: [This.](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes) I have seen many example projects where this was taken literally in the form of a renderer.js file.

Comment: @temporary_user_name this was the exact question I was wondering. The starter project and docs need to be fixed because they make it sound like these file names are required when they are not. In addition, I have found that preload.js can be named anything as well, and if you don't need it, neither a preload or renderer js file is even required. The docs are really misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using `Electron` for a few years now and I have never, ever used a "renderer.js" file. I tend to use "app.js" or something more specific to the app but it is just habit.

It doesn't matter what the files are named - you could call "main.js" anything -  "late-for-dinner.js" and so long as you reference it as the entry point in your `package.json` all will be well. Same for "renderer.js"

I would guess that the names "main.js" and "renderer.js" were picked to illustrate the separate domains, not because they are in any way "required",